# pug - create a layout for header including login / logout links

Tags: node.js, pug

In my Express JS web app, I need to create a layout view that is attached to every other view as included. The layout is supposed to contain a header and a login or logout link depending user authentication condition.

layout.pug:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='/jquery/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')    
    block extraHeader
    block extraScript
  body
    block content
```

home.pug that contains the layout on the top which may contain a log out link if user was already logged in.

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

How can I generate the header in `layout.pug`?

Comment: What do you mean by generating header in `layour.pug`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code in between the `body` tag and `block content`:

```
body
  div Header goes here
  block content
```

You can use conditional logic to control a button in there too:

```
body
  div Header goes here
  if(user)
    button(onclick='logout()') Logout
  else
    button(onclick='login()') Login
  block content
```

In one line using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
body
  div Header goes here
  button(onclick= user ? "logout()" : "login()")= user ? "Logout" : "Login"
  block content
```

Of course, this assumes that your route passes a variable named "user" in the render function.